# Использование Page load strategy для Chrome driver через php-webdriver

Tags: php, парсер, selenium, chromedriver, facebook-php-webdriver

Разрабатываю парсер интернет-магазина на PHP. Задача: необходимо получить html-код каталога товаров, не дожидаясь полной загрузки сайта.

Для этой цели использую [PHP Webdriver](https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver) с браузером Chrome ([ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) 81.0.4044.69). Чтобы магазин меня не забанил, использую прокси, что несколько замедляет загрузку сайта. Проблема заключается в том, что html-код каталога появляется в первые секунды загрузки, но команды после `$driver->get('....')` не будут выполняться, пока магазин не загрузится полностью со всеми скриптами, стилями, картинками и т.д. С целью увеличения производительности парсера хотелось бы,чтобы как только появился html-код каталога, прерывать загрузку и переходить к дальнейшему анализу полученного html.

```
    host = 'http://localhost:4444';
    $options = new ChromeOptions();

    $options->addArguments([
        '--window-size=1500,800',
        '-proxy-server=socks4://IPпрокси:ПортПрокси',
    ]);

    $desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities::chrome();
    $desiredCapabilities->setCapability(ChromeOptions::CAPABILITY, $options);

    $driver = RemoteWebDriver::create($host, $desiredCapabilities);
    $content = $driver->get('https://www.какой-то-интернет-магазин.ru/')->getPageSource();
    // ждёт полной загрузки страницы и только потом выполняется дальше
    $catalog = ... анализ html: вытаскиваю из $content интересующий меня фрагмент каталога;
    file_put_contents('Catalog.html', $catalog);
```

Лучшее решение этой проблемы без костылей - это использование [Page load strategy](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/en/webdriver/page_loading_strategy/) в режиме eager или none. Знаю, что это возможно с версии ChromeDriver 77.0. Нашёл [решение для других языков программирования](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0), однако мне не хватает опыта, чтобы реализовать тоже самое на PHP Webdriver. Также [здесь](http://barancev.github.io/slow-loading-pages/) рассказывается о:

1) костыльном методе через таймаут ожидания загрузки, но не факт, что нужный мне элемент успеет загрузиться за явно выставленное время;

2) нужной мне стратегии ожидания загрузки, но опять-таки не понятно, как это реализовать на PHP Webdriver.

Comment: А зачем вам использовать драйвер? Почему нельзя запросить и скачать страницу через аналоги curl, там же должно быть только HTML/CSS/Javascript? А после этого уже выдираете что вам нужно так как ссылки в HEAD таким путём скачиваться не будут. У вас сейчас основная проблема - это что драйвер предоставляет полный цикл обработки и загрузки страницы а-ля браузер. Обойдите это с простым скачиванием кода страницы.

Comment: Если я вас правильно понимаю, то вот здесь в комментариях дал объяснение, почему пошёл этим путём: https://qna.habr.com/q/761869

Comment: Нет, это не объясняет почему. Если только из-за прокси - то прокси можно настроить и в CURL.

Comment: Дело в том, что сайт выдаёт сначала обфусцированный js-код без каких-либо явных ссылок для перехода. Чтобы его исполнить, нужен софт, который бы поддерживал исполнение js. Если просто получить этот js-код через curl или аналоги, ничего я с ним дальше сделать не смогу. Поэтому и начал копать в сторону браузерных движков. А на оптимизацию загрузки через остановку загрузки страницы на нужном мне моменте меня натолкнуло неизбежное использование прокси, которое раза в 2-3 уменьшает скорость выполнения скрипта

Comment: А каким образом JS завязан с HTML, который вы собираетесь обрабатывать? Думаю вам стоит переосмыслить и отредактировать свой вопрос чтобы он включал в себя всю полноту картины, с которой вы столкнулись, дополнить это информацией из своих комментариев, а уже после этого ждать что вам смогут на него ответить.

Answer (score 0):

Спросил ответ у официальных разработчиков библиотеки на Github, они мне ответили здесь: https://github.com/php-webdriver/php-webdriver/issues/786